# iterating specific entries of a list

Tags: list, lua, iteration, lua-table

Given is a table like:

```
t = {mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun, spe, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, bar1, bar2, bar3, some_other_stuff, ... } 
-- assumed that all entries are existing objects
```

Now I want to iterate through all the "day"-objects and give them a callback.

Is there something like (pseudo):

```
for _,v in pairs(t.{mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun,spe})do
   v.callback = function()
      foo(bar)
   end
end
```

So as you see I want to iterate through a specific part of that table. Is this possible?
In my example it's not really neccesary due the callback is very simple. 
But I'm trying to make a factory constructor and with bare hands this is grinding my gears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [your solution](//stackoverflow.com/a/26709735/1190388) is sufficient, a more efficient way would be to define a new table:

```
do
    local days = { 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun' }
    for _, v in ipairs( dayes ) do
       t[v].callback = function()
          foo(bar)
       end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Uh nevermind, it's that simple:

```
for _,v in pairs({t.mon, t.tue, t.wed, ...})do
   -- do your job
end
```